# Float adds unnecessary space

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to design a mouseover description:
Sometimes including one or two extra "infos"
- and for once floats seem to be in order, but:

[image: Outcome]

[image]

Why is "15 min." pushed out beyond then end of "maskine" ?
- Can I compact it somehow, to get a straight right margin ?

**Solution**: Each line of white text must be in it's own span (to not form a single square box):

[image]

Comment: Could you provide valid HTML?  For somebody with your rep, I'm surprised at the lack of formatting of your question

Comment: Sorry, just wanted to leave out irrelevant stuff...

Comment: Knowing what type the tag is is **not** irrelevant

Comment: It's also difficult to know exactly how you want it to react.  What happens if the first line (currently `Plysning`) is longer that the 2nd line?  What is supposed to happen to the time element then?

Comment: Just take op at little space as possible : ) - I did get my answer from Michael Rose - the (br) doesn't end the box - I need a separate span for each line. Adding the solution to the question, now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not add "unnecessary" space - it just doesn't know that there is space available in the bounding box of the text (Plysning ...).

One possibility would be to position the 15min text absolute with a `top: 0px; right: 0px;` and use `text-align: right;`. Remember to then use `position: relative;` on the purple wrapping container.

Comment: So the middle (white) text is considered a box, even if the top line doesn't fill it.. I'm trying to avoid positioning (I don't know the size of any of the 1,2 or 3 elements..

Comment: I pretty much agree with what you're saying @Michael, but wouldn't that cause an overlap if the 1st line was longer than the 2nd line?

Comment: Got it. I split the (white) text on (br) and join it again with each chunk in a seperate left:floating span separated by (br)'s : )

Comment: Sorry for my late comment - @freefaller yes you are right, it would cause an overlap! I (probably falsely) assumed that this would not be the case...